# Weird whitespace border around entire site

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I've only just started to get this, but any web development I do (wordpress, simple html) has this whitespace border around the entire site. This (I quickly did it for testing):

http://puu.sh/2OShe.png

There is nothing in the code that is doing this. I only have a list in the html, and css properties that don't affect it. (I've deleted everything but 1 line of text, and it still borders the entire html).

I'm going crazy, and assume it isn't like this if I viewed it elsewhere, but it annoys the hell out of me when developing.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that your browser is loading a user style sheet you aren't aware of?  Also, a plugin or add-on might be affecting your browser's rendering.

Comment: It's the same across firefox, chrome and IE. McMastermind solved it for me, but why was it doing this in the first place? No idea how to check if the browser is loading some secret css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set your body padding and margin to 0

```
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

Comment: I want to neck myself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: we all make mistakes.. wait until you explore JS a bit and realize that a missing semi-colon, missing bracket, or trailing comma completely destroys your code.. glad i could help, welcome to SO, and don't forget to accept an answer.

Comment: to answer your comment above, HTML body element defaults with 8px padding all around.. idk why.. it just does.. always apply a [simple css reset](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-reset/) when starting to style a webpage.. and if you need some developer tools, hit F12 in Chrome.. here you can see all applied styles and edit on the fly..